# Is there a way to use ODBC to give users ability to download MySQL as a formatted excel file?

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, odbc

I have a survey site that collects data from user inputs and stores it in MySQL.

I want some users to be able to go to a page that allows them to download a formatted excel file of the data (note, not a csv).

I've heard ODBC allows you to interface excel with MySQL, but can't find any server side applications for it.

Is it possible?

I'm using PHP for the site.

Thanks

Comment: You would only need to make an ODBC connection if you wanted to give Excel dynamic access to the MySQL data.  If you are satisfied with a download this is overkill.  Some details on connecting Excel with MySQL can be found here: http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/

Comment: Thanks to both of you for these suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting a database to an excel file should not be difficult since excel can read xhtml.

Just output your information as a regular HTML table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>record1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and then add these headers to force automatic download and interpretation as an excel file:

```
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$yourFileName}\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
```

It should work as intended.

EDIT:
Here's an example of a table to xls with correct XHTML schema:

```
<?php
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=newtest.xls" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
?>
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta name="Excel Workbook">
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 14">
<style>
#test
{
    font-style:italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>header in bold</b></td>
        <td><i>header in italic</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><span style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic">my data with css styling</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><span id="test">I'm italic 'cause I can read style</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see, is it possible to state formatting requirements using this method? e.g. make the column headers bold

Comment: Yes, you can use css to style anyway you want.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for putting such effort into a detailed answer!